# Counting different tables in MyISAM MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I wrote the code below as an example to fetch from different [MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) MySQL tables and I can't use UNION to count and only the **first value turns correct and the other is empty**.

Actually which is first and that's because I heard my tables are MyISAM.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS userCount from table_users)
UNION 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalposts from table_stories)
```

So what's the solution?

Comment: What results do you expect? I just tried your query and it works as expected with both MyISAM and INNODB tables. And why do use aliases here?

Comment: What I'd expect from that query: 2 data rows, one with userCount of n, and totalposts of NULL, and a second row with userCount of NULL and totalposts of m (where m and n are your counts). If you want a single column with both results, the selects that make up your union have to have the same column name.

Comment: question, since not using where, group, join, a simple lookup on `Rows` on `SHOW TABLE STATUS` does everything exactly, or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both results in the same row, you could use subqueries for that. Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE table_users (id int) ENGINE=MYISAM;
CREATE TABLE table_stories (id int) ENGINE=MYISAM;

INSERT INTO table_users VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO table_stories VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) from table_users) userCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) from table_stories) totalposts;
+-----------+------------+
| userCount | totalposts |
+-----------+------------+
|         3 |          6 |
+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If on the other hand you want your results in separate rows, the query that you were using should work as well:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_value from table_users)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) from table_stories);
+-------------+
| count_value |
+-------------+
|           3 |
|           6 |
+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: wow , your first query  worked fine  , but i dont know why the second one is not !????

Comment: @Mac: do you get a `NULL` row for the second query?